# How to remove duplicate objects from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

This is my code

```js
var studentsList = [
    {"Id": "101", "name": "siva"},
    {"Id": "101", "name": "siva"},
    {"Id": "102", "name": "hari"},
    {"Id": "103", "name": "rajesh"},
    {"Id": "103", "name": "rajesh"},
    {"Id": "104", "name": "ramesh"},
];

function arrUnique(arr) {
    var cleaned = [];
    studentsList.forEach(function(itm) {
        var unique = true;
        cleaned.forEach(function(itm2) {
            if (_.isEqual(itm, itm2)) unique = false;
        });
        if (unique)  cleaned.push(itm);
    });
    return cleaned;
}

var uniqueStandards = arrUnique(studentsList);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(uniqueStandards, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

OutPut

```
[
{
    "Id": "101",
    "name": "siva"
},
{
    "Id": "102",
    "name": "hari"
},
{
    "Id": "103",
    "name": "rajesh"
},
{
    "Id": "104",
    "name": "ramesh"
}
]
```

In the above code I got unique objects from the JavaScript array, but i want to remove duplicate objects. So I want to get without duplicate objects from the array, the output like 
    [
    {
        "Id": "102",
        "name": "hari"
    },
    {
        "Id": "104",
        "name": "ramesh"
    }
    ]

Comment: why you don't use lodash or underscore lib?

Comment: Use `lodash` for better productivity: https://lodash.com/docs#uniq

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular?

Answer (score 18):

Check this

```
    var uniqueStandards = UniqueArraybyId(studentsList ,"id");

    function UniqueArraybyId(collection, keyname) {
              var output = [], 
                  keys = [];

              angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
                  var key = item[keyname];
                  if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                      keys.push(key);
                      output.push(item);
                  }
              });
        return output;
   };
```

Comment: it's accept case sensitivity. It shows 'Electronics' and 'electronics' are different words.

Answer (score 4):

This maybe? (not the most performant implementation but gets the job done):

```
var studentsList = [
  {Id: "101", name: "siva"},
  {Id: "101", name: "siva"},
  {Id: "102", name: "hari"},
  {Id: "103", name: "rajesh"},
  {Id: "103", name: "rajesh"},
  {Id: "104", name: "ramesh"},
];

var ids = {};

studentsList.forEach(function (student) {
  ids[student.Id] = (ids[student.Id] || 0) + 1;
});

var output = [];
studentsList.forEach(function (student) {
  if (ids[student.Id] === 1) output.push(student);
});

console.log(output);
```

Edit: faster method **if the students are ordered by Id**:

```
var studentsList = [
  {Id: "101", name: "siva"},
  {Id: "101", name: "siva"},
  {Id: "102", name: "hari"},
  {Id: "103", name: "rajesh"},
  {Id: "103", name: "rajesh"},
  {Id: "104", name: "ramesh"},
];

var output = [];
studentsList.reduce(function (isDup, student, index) {
  var nextStudent = studentsList[index + 1];
  if (nextStudent && student.Id === nextStudent.Id) {
    return true;
  } else if (isDup) {
    return false;
  } else {
    output.push(student);
  }

  return false;
}, false);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var unique = arr.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation as to why this code works, so it's a more useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's `filter` method:

The solution for the above problem can be found in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/varun1989/6ceadt4L/) fiddle.
The performance of this solution will be better because we are using pure javascript and there is no third party overhead.

```
app.controller('myCntrl',function($scope){

    var seen = {};
    //You can filter based on Id or Name based on the requirement
    var uniqueStudents = studentsList.filter(function(item){
    if(seen.hasOwnProperty(item.Id)){
        return false;
    }else{
        seen[item.Id] = true;
        return true;
    }
});
    $scope.students = uniqueStudents;

});
```

Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: I'm affraid it's exactly not what he's looking for.

Comment: @varun - your code will return unique objects like 101,102,103,104 but i want to getting 102,104

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller which will detect the duplicate element and remove it and will give you the element which has no duplicates. Just use this controller

```
$scope.names= studentsList.reduce(function(array, place) {
         if (array.indexOf( studentsList.name) < 0) 
                array.push( studentsList.name );
         else
                array.splice(array.indexOf( studentsList.name), 1);
         return array;
}, []);
```

Hope this works for your case

Answer (score 0):

You can use library **lodash** and method `uniqBy()`

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner function using `Set()`?

```
function arrUnique(arr) { return [...new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);}
```

It uses `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to transform the objects to string, because the equality function of `Set()` (`===`) is not customizable and doesn't work for objects, but for strings. `JSON.parse()` of the unique elements in the stringified version transforms them back to objects.

Very likely, this is not the fastest version because of overhead using JSON methods.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, two different examples, the first gets all duplicates comparing a property rather than an Id or comparing the whole object. The second example is is a distinct list of duplicates.

```js
// Sample 1 - Show all duplicates of a particular code rather than the whole record is unique

var sampleJson = 
[
  { id: 1, code: "123-123" }, 
  { id: 2, code: "123-124" }, 
  { id: 3, code: "123-125" }, 
  { id: 4, code: "123-123" }
];

console.log("All duplicates");

let duplicates= [];

sampleJson.forEach(function (item) {
  var checkForDuplicates = sampleJson.filter(a => a.code == item.code);
  if (checkForDuplicates.length > 1) {
    duplicates .push(item);
  }
});
console.log(duplicates);
console.log( "Distinct duplicates");


// Sample 2 - Distinct list of duplicates
let distinctDuplicates= [];

sampleJson.forEach(function(item) {

  var checkForDuplicates = sampleJson.filter(a => a.code == item.code);
  if (checkForDuplicates.length > 1) {

    // Ensure we only have the single duplicate by ensuring we do not add the same one twice
    var exists = distinctDuplicates.filter(b => b.code == item.code).length == 1;
    if (false === exists) {
      distinctDuplicates.push(item);
    }
  }
});
console.log(distinctDuplicates);
```